# Calculate body volume using kinect

Tags: c++, kinect, volume

I need an algorithm for calculating the body volume (in cubic meters) using kinect.
I know I can extract the cloud and the depth frame (isolating the body by using some methods of the skeleton NUI) but I don't know how to calculate the volume value from this matrix.
Exporting a volume block would be of any help?

Comment: Cool. And then you can calculate how much trash bags you need for particular body.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to compute the body volume precisely you can use the algorithm for generating Avatars from Kinect for monitoring obesity as it is demonstrated in this video, which shows an example of computing the volume of pregnant women using Kinect. [Watch demo video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBSiiOIEiPI)

The algorithm is described in details in the technical paper: A. Barmpoutis. 'Tensor Body: Real-time Reconstruction of the Human Body and Avatar Synthesis from RGB-D', IEEE Transactions on Cybernetics, Special issue on Computer Vision for RGB-D Sensors: Kinect and Its Applications, October 2013, Vol. 43(5), Pages: 1347-1356. [Read PDF.](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/Kinect_Avatars.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If you have depth and can determine distance via kinect sensor, and hence height, then you have x, y centimeters dimensions, via depth distance per z delta, and a rough z/2 per pixel/ray cloud-based approximation of depth cm. Keep in mind that human anterior and posterior are asymmetrical (hence the "rough" z/2 approximation - multiplying by 2).

If you can formalize a model of the human form, you can create a fitting algorithm that gives better approximate volume based on the given sensor information.